# Editing XML in Windows Store using MVVM and Message

Tags: c#, xml, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my application I am creating XML in [App.xaml.cs](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Win8/App.xaml.cs) like this:

```
public  async static void CreateBadgesXML()
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Data", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile st = await sf.CreateFileAsync("Badgess.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement x;

        x = dom.CreateElement("badges");
        dom.AppendChild(x);

        XmlElement x1 = dom.CreateElement("badge");

        XmlElement x11 = dom.CreateElement("id");
        x11.InnerText = "1";
        x1.AppendChild(x11);

        XmlElement x12 = dom.CreateElement("name");
        x12.InnerText = "Badge One";
        x1.AppendChild(x12);

        XmlElement x13 = dom.CreateElement("pictureurl");
        x13.InnerText = "two.png";
        x1.AppendChild(x13);

        XmlElement x14 = dom.CreateElement("isachieved");
        x14.InnerText = "false";
        x1.AppendChild(x14);

        x.AppendChild(x1);

        await dom.SaveToFileAsync(st);
    }
```

Next in [MainViewModel](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs) I am binding these data using reposiory pattern to ObservableCollection like this:

```
IList<Badge> list = await _badgeService.GetAll();

BadgesList = list.ToObservableCollection<Badge>();
```

But when I am going to edit this XML in another View which is connected to another VievModel ([QuestionViewModel](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/QuestionViewModel.cs)) like this:

```
public async Task Update(int id)
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Data", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile st = await sf.CreateFileAsync("Badgess.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement x;

        x = dom.CreateElement("badges");
        dom.AppendChild(x);

        XmlElement x1 = dom.CreateElement("badge");

        XmlElement x11 = dom.CreateElement("id");
        x11.InnerText = "1";
        x1.AppendChild(x11);

        XmlElement x12 = dom.CreateElement("name");
        x12.InnerText = "Badge One";
        x1.AppendChild(x12);

        XmlElement x13 = dom.CreateElement("pictureurl");
        x13.InnerText = "two.png";
        x1.AppendChild(x13);

        XmlElement x14 = dom.CreateElement("isachieved");
        x14.InnerText = "true";
        x1.AppendChild(x14);

        x.AppendChild(x1);

        await dom.SaveToFileAsync(st);
    }
```

And sending a Message from QuestionViewModel to MainViewModel like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<CleanUp>(new CleanUp());
```

And try to bind this collection again:

```
private void CallCleanUp(CleanUp obj)
    {
        BadgesList = null;
        GetBadges();
    }
```

I get an error XmlException "Root element is missing." I do not understand why after XML update, content of this file is empty? Any ideas?

**EDIT**
After changes in update method, now I've got an UnauthorizedAccessException in `GetAll()` method in my [BadgeService](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Win8/Services/XML/BadgeService.cs), still strange because in appears only after update XML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
dom.AppendChild(x);
```

after this:

```
x.AppendChild(x1);
```

I think you should add x to your xml file after creating x1 and x.